# About the address layout of struct in c/c++

Tags: c, struct

Is it true that the first element always at a lower address than the last element,no matter whether it's in stack or heap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a C++ compiler re-order elements in a struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916600/can-a-c-compiler-re-order-elements-in-a-struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, yes. The elements of a `struct` are located in memory in the same order they're defined in the `struct` definition. They may have padding between them (but there's guaranteed to be no padding before the first one, and a pointer to a `struct` can be safely cast to a pointer to the first element of that `struct`), but they always get laid out in memory in the same order.

Can we ask why you're asking?

Comment: But the book I'm reading says it depends on endianness,so it's not always true the first element is at lower address or not.

Comment: @compile-fan - Endianness should affect the ordering of bytes within an integer, but I don't believe the standard says that that affects the ordering of different variables relative to each other.

Comment: It could affect the order of bitfield elements, but they do not have addresses, so strictly speaking they don't have an "order in memory".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assume that objects of a given class are all laid out the same way in memory, no matter where they are stored.

Note that the above doesn't imply anything about *which* end is stored at a lower address. The compiler may choose to reorder the fields of the class as it sees fit.

Comment: I don't think the compiler can reorder the fields of a `struct` but I'm doing homework so I'm not going to check the standard.

Comment: Ok, point taken. The compiler is substantially less free than I may have implied.

Comment: do you mean that the first element of `struct` differs in little and bigger endian?

Comment: @compile-fan: No, the structure layout has nothing to do with endianness.