# How to remove unused data-members?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, constexpr, datamember

The following code contains an example template `X`, where the data-member is unused, if the template is parametrized with other type than `A`. But the sizes of the objects `a` and `b` are the same, even with `-O3`, so the optimizer does not remove the unused data-member `x2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename T>
struct X {
    int value() const {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
            return x1 + x2;
        }
        else {
            return x1;
        }
    }
private:
    int x1{0};    
    int x2{0};    
};

int main() {
    X<A> a;
    X<B> b;
    
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(b) << '\n';
    return a.value() + b.value();
}
```

Now there are two questions:

1. Is the optimizer not allowed (`as-if`-rule) to remove the unused data-member? Why?
2. How to achieve the goal: that the class `X<B>` does not contain the unused data-member `x2`?

There is a workaround with a base-class template and a specialisation for `A` that contains the data-member `x2`. But this solution is cumbersome. I wonder if there is a solution without using a base class?

Edit:
I don't think that using the `sizeof()` operator prevents the optimization:

```
//#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename T>
struct X {
    int value() const {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
            return x1 + x2;
        }
        else {
            return x1;
        }
    }
private:
    int x1{0};    
    int x2{1};    
};

X<A> a;
X<B> b;


int main() {
//    std::cout << sizeof(a) << '\n';
//    std::cout << sizeof(b) << '\n';
    return a.value() + b.value();
}
```

If you look a the assembly (e.g. compiler explorer) you see that the instances contain in both cases both data-members.

Comment: seems like you have your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125503/1632887)

Comment: Surely that fact that you are printing the sizeof these objects prevents removal of the data member. It's not unused if it's part of a sizeof calculation.

Comment: As I know, the compiler is disallowed to remove the unused variable (as-if rule).
See discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176564/can-unused-data-members-be-optimized-out-in-c and this [post](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/12/02/unused-private-member/). Clang can warn about unused private data memer, but doesn't work here.

Comment: @wimalopaan I'm not certain but I think you are wrong, using sizeof does prevent the optimisation. Of course other things may be preventing the optimization as well.

Comment: *"But this solution is cumbersome."* You have several ways to handle the specialization (just the data field or the full class).

Comment: @Nimrod: Do you know the reason why it is supported to access the private members via this so called "loophole": the explicit instantiation of templates?

Comment: @wimalopaan: It allows (legit) custom specialization of `std::hash<SomeClass::InnerPrivateClass>`.

Comment: @wimalopaan That's another question lol. Simply put, the standard allows it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an ugly solution if x1 and x2 has the same type:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
    int value() const {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
            return x1() + x2();
        }
        else {
            return x1();
        }
    }

    int x1() const {
        return x[0];
    }

    int x2() const {
        return x[1];
    }

private:
    //int x1{0};    
    //int x2{0};
    int x[1 + std::is_same_v<T, A>] = {};
};
```

Comment: @JasonLiam in fact you are both wrong and right :) The first example (and also the original one) has it both 0, but the second/below one is different as you said.

Answer (score -1):

> Is the optimizer not allowed (as-if-rule) to remove the unused data-member?

Just because an implementation *can* do something, doesn't mean that it *does* do that thing. And the act of observing the size of your type might prompt the implementation to choose not to omit the "unused" data member.

It is a relatively common idiom to have unused data members to ensure a particular size and layout of a data type, so implementations are likely to take at face value the declarations in a type.

> How to achieve the goal: that the class X does not contain the unused data-member x2?

There are numerous ways, including moving the data members to a base class, and inherit conditionally.

```
namespace detail {

    struct XA {
        int x1{0};    
        int x2{0};    
    };
    
    struct XB {
        int x1{0};  
    };   
}

template<typename T>
struct X : private std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, A>, detail::XA, detail::XB>{
    int value() const {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
            return x1 + x2;
        }
        else {
            return x1;
        }
    }   
};
```