# Are there any methods or tools to find the most compacted layout of a class in C++?

Tags: c++

C++ compilers can add paddings between fields in a class. With my compiler, `X1` has size 24, and `X2` has size 18. I know the final size is kind of compiler-bound, and relevant to alignment.

However, I wonder if there are some ways that can find the most compact layout in a certain compiling environment. Note that we are not going to change alignments or compiling options, we only change the order of different fields.

```
// Size = 24
struct X1 {
    uint8_t a;
    uint64_t b;
    uint8_t c;
};

// Size = 18
struct X2 {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t c;
    uint64_t b;
};
```

I've tried to think about the problem, maybe we can develop some tools to do that. However, I am not familiar with compiling systems.

Meanwhile, I also wonder if we can always have a best solution here? Given the following example, if I change `X` to its most compact layout, could it do some harm to `Y`, thus making Y takes actually larger spaces?
Furthermore, if we start from optimizing layout of `Y`, we could end up with optimizing layout of `X`, and thus resulting in some recursive logic. I am quite lost here...

```
struct Y {
    X x;
    uint32_t x2;
}
```

Comment: In general, ordering members from largest to smallest should eliminate most|all padding.  However, sometimes you want suboptimal layouts in order to avoid things like false sharing.

Comment: Usually you can just order fields by size. In the last example, either `X` has alignment >4 and has to go first (otherwise you waste at least 4 bytes) or it has alignment <=4 and it doesn't matter if it's first or not.

Comment: you can use [clang-reorder-fields tool in clang-tools-extra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28780286/995714) to automatically reorder the fields so that the size is smallest

Comment: Managing the layout is possible in various ways, like reordering and also most compilers allow for hints like packing/alignment (e.g. #pragma pack). But be aware there might be a price to pay at runtime, unaligned data can be a lot slower to access. So "Best" solution is a tradeoff between memory size and speed (as is often the case)

Comment: This feels like a solution in search for a problem. Is this just plain curiosity (which is fine)? Or is there some underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, Actually I have a struct `X` that may have more than 10k+ instances, and the struct is so nested and has many fields, which makes me hard to manually resolve. So I want a tool for that.

Comment: Brand latest version of Visual Studio 2022 17.9 now has a great feature to visualize the memory layout of structures. It doesn't optimize automatically them, but can surely help. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-9-now-available/#c-memory-layout-visualization