# Variadic aggregates as core language feature

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, c++17

`std::tuple` is highly template-loaded beast. To access to n-th member compiler must perform a plenty of template instantiations, although its simple nature: access to n-th data member of corresponding imaginary struct. It seems that `std::tuple` should be a core language feature, something like this (pseudocode):

```
template< typename ...types >
struct/* or class, or even union */ V
{
    types... V; // defines implicitly `operator [/*constant expression*/]` to access by index
    // if more than one variadic parameter pack provided
    // (during expanding of parameter pack of template 
    // parameters in specializations) then instead of
    // `V` there can be specific data-member name (say, `x`),
    // but still with `x.operator []` implicitly defined

    // member functions and data members allowed
};

template< typename ...types >
V< std::decay_t< types >... > make_tuple(types &&... args)
{ return {std::forward< types >(args)...}; }
template< typename ...types >
V< types &&... > forward_as_tuple(types &&... args)
{ return {std::forward< types >(args)...}; }
template< typename ...types >
V< types &... > tie(types &... args)
{ return {args...}; }
```

Is there any proposal of something like language supported variadic data-members definition syntax for classes?

Comment: What is the advantage of making it core-language feature? why only `std::tuple`? why not `std::vector` also? My thought is that if something can be done as library feature, it should be done, *only if* that is not possible (or too hacky to do that) it makes sense to add it language feature.

Comment: @Nawaz POD array (single type, multiple values) already present in language, `int x[3] = {1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: Regardless about `types... V;`, `operator[](size_t)` cannot possibly exist.

Comment: @Barry above syntax is just *my* proposal. I want to see a real proposal maden by professionals from the Committee. BTW, C-arrays has `operator []` implicitly defined in some sense and C-structs has operator `.` to access to data members.

Comment: @Barry OK, instead of `[]` I can propose a variable template-like syntax via `< std::size_t >`.

Comment: @Nawaz, have you looked at the definition of `std::tuple` recently? It's disgusting. A core language feature would just do the right thing. I've been threatening to propose something like this for a while.

Comment: C++ core language is a beast. It's high time to start removing features from it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Just have to state that you can declare variables of type pack expansion and throw in some wording about how `T... v;` is equivalent to `T0 v0; T1 v1; T2 v2; ... Tn vn;`?

Comment: @Barry rather, it should be equivalent to `T.[0] v<0>; .. T.[n] v<n>;` [using n4235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4235.htm) -- ie, I'd have it define a variable template (!) `template<size_t n> T.[n] v;`  You'd then access the variable template the way you'd access any other variable template.  Of course, variable templates in structs are not currently allowed, but a variable template with explicit instantiation should be viable in a `struct`...  So, template member variables, and a syntax to declare a subset of them...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [N4235 Selecting from Parameter Packs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4235.htm) for a related idea.

That might be useful for `std::tuple`, but I'm more interested in a feature to simplify its construction, not selection of members (which is comparatively simple).

The definition of `std::tuple` is insanely complicated, in order to make all the constructors correctly model the properties of all the members (see [N4064](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4064.html) for the most recent changes in that area).

When you use aggregate-initialization the compiler automatically checks whether each member of the aggregate can be constructed from the corresponding initializers. It checks for suitable constructors, whether they are `explicit`, accept the relevant lvalue/rvalue category etc.

When you define a constructor for `std::tuple` is has to be very complicated to ensure that only valid conversions happen, that `explicit` constructors are not used when they shouldn't be etc.

I'd like a feature that made it much easier to automatically generate suitable constructors to model the same semantics as you get for free from aggregate initialization.

Comment: And we haven’t even gone into implementing a literal type variadic `variant<Xs...>` ;)

Comment: @LucDanton, yeah, I'm not touching that topic with a 10' pole! :)

Comment: Interesting how would looks like an answer to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120386/), if the proposal will become a part of the standard?