# std::tuple sizeof, is it a missed optimization?

Tags: c++, tuples, language-lawyer, padding

I've checked all major compilers, and `sizeof(std::tuple<int, char, int, char>)` is 16 for all of them. Presumably they just put elements in order into the tuple, so some space is wasted because of alignment.

If tuple stored elements internally like: `int, int, char, char`, then its sizeof could be 12.

Is it possible for an implementation to do this, or is it forbidden by some rule in the standard?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198907/discussion-on-question-by-geza-stdtuple-sizeof-is-it-a-missed-optimization).

Comment: related: [Is there a GCC keyword to allow structure-reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14671253/995714), [Can a C++ compiler re-order elements in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916600/995714), [Why doesn't GCC optimize structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118068/995714), [Automated field re-ordering in C structs to avoid padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/867471/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: There's a big difference between a `struct` and a `tuple` => one is a language construct, the other a library type. Why would you think that they must obey the same rules?

Comment: @MatthieuM. where did I say that they obey the same rules?

Comment: @phuclv: Then what is the point of the related questions? If they obey different rules, looking at the rules for struct does not help.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> std::tuple sizeof, is it a missed optimization?

Yep.

> Is it possible for an implementation to do this[?]

Yep.

> [Is] it forbidden by some rule in the standard?

Nope!

Reading through `[tuple]`, there is no constraint placed upon the implementation to store the members in template-argument order.

In fact, every passage I can find seems to go to lengths to avoid making any reference to member-declaration order at all: `get<N>()` is used in the description of operational semantics. Other wording is stated in terms of "elements" rather than "members", which seems like quite a deliberate abstraction.

In fact, [some implementations do apparently store the members in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14608924/560648), at least, probably simply due to the way they use inheritance recursively to unpack the template arguments (and because, as above, they're permitted to).

Speaking specifically about your hypothetical optimisation, though, I'm not aware of any implementation that doesn't store elements in [some trivial function of] the user-given order; I'm guessing that it would be "hard" to come up with such an order and to provide the machinery for `std::get`, at least as compared to the amount of gain you'd get from doing so. If you are really concerned about padding, you may of course choose your element order carefully to avoid it (on some given platform), much as you would with a class (without delving into the world of "packed" attributes). *(A "packed" tuple could be an interesting proposal…)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199001/discussion-on-answer-by-lightness-races-in-orbit-stdtuple-sizeof-is-it-a-miss).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's possible and has been (mostly) done by [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes). He used to have a blog called *Flaming Danger Zone*, which is now down for some reason, but its [sources are still available on github](https://github.com/rmartinho/flamingdangerzone).

Here are the all four parts of the *Size Matters* series on this exact topic: [1](https://github.com/rmartinho/flamingdangerzone/blob/master/_posts/cxx11/2012-07-06-optimal-tuple-i.md), [2](https://github.com/rmartinho/flamingdangerzone/blob/master/_posts/cxx11/2012-12-02-optimal-tuple-ii.md), [3](https://github.com/rmartinho/flamingdangerzone/blob/master/_posts/cxx11/2012-12-09-optimal-tuple-iii.md), [4](https://github.com/rmartinho/flamingdangerzone/blob/master/_posts/cxx11/2013-02-18-optimal-tuple-iv.md).

You might wish to view them raw since github doesn't understand C++ highlighting markup used and renders code snippets as unreadable oneliners.

He essentially computes a permutation for tuple indices via C++11 template meta-program, that sorts elements by alignment in non-ascending order, stores the elements according to it, and then applies it to the index on every access.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. A better way would be to sort by alignment (instead of size).

Comment: @geza my bad, he does actually sort by alignment.

Comment: Note that this says nothing about whether the standard `tuple` is permitted to work this way. So, although it's very interesting, it doesn't really answer the question

Comment: The site is up and "running" but it seems to have been taken over by a domain squatter running a phishing attack. Tells me I've won 1 out of 100 tablet computers if I tell them my google password or something.

Answer (score -3):

They could. One possible reason they don’t: some architectures, including x86, have an indexing mode that can address an address *base* + *size* × *index* in a single instruction—but only when *size* is a power of 2.  Or it might be slightly faster to do a load or store aligned to a 16-byte boundary. This could make code that addresses arrays of `std::tuple` slightly faster and more compact if they add four padding bytes.